# Unable to access registry using util extension

Tags: wix, burn

I was trying to search a registry on Burn within a fragment. 
I used the following snippet

> ```
> <util:RegistrySearch Id="VCRedistributables" 
>                          Root="HKLM"
>                          Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\6F9E66FF7E38E3A3FA41D89E8A906A4A\InstallProperties"
>                          Variable="VCREDISTISINSTALLED"
>                          Value="DisplayVersion" 
>                          Result="exists"/>
> ```

But the log says

> [1AA8:0E4C][2014-01-31T11:09:51]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\6F9E66FF7E38E3A3FA41D89E8A906A4A\InstallProperties'

I searched the registry manually to find the registry key and value. However Burn was unable to find it. What is the reason for that? I am suing Wix 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are dealing with x64-based versions of Windows. There is [two registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459/en), in this Windows. Check availability of this key in both branches.